# Connection closes between client and server communicating using ssl socket with self signed certificate

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, self-signed-certificate

I am trying to simulate an ssl encrypted comminication over TCP between server and client on localhost with self signed certificate. I don't care to verification, so I have disabled the security in client context.

server.py

```
import ssl
import socket

cert_file = "cert.pem" #contains the private key and the certificate

server_addr = ('localhost', 8888)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ctx = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
    ctx.load_cert_chain(cert_file)

    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as server_socket:
        server_socket.bind(server_addr)
        server_socket.listen(1)
        client_socket, _ = server_socket.accept()
        conn_stream = ctx.wrap_socket(client_socket, server_side=True)
        message = conn_stream.recv(1024)
        print(f'Client sent - "{message.decode()}"')
        conn_stream.close()
```

client.py

```
import ssl
import socket


server_addr = ('localhost', 8888)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
    ctx.check_hostname = False
    ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as client_socket:
        ssl_socket = ctx.wrap_socket(client_socket)
        ssl_socket.connect(server_addr)
        message = "Knock knock, our messages are encrypted with ssl"
        ssl_socket.send(message.encode())
        ssl_socket.close()
```

When I run the server.py and then client.py I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\whocares\Documents\server.py", line 16, in <module>
    conn_stream = ctx.wrap_socket(client_socket, server_side=True)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

What am I doing wrong here? How do I successfully send the message with SSL?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error; the programs work for me.

Comment: I was using a windows machine to run this program when I received the error. I used WSL to run this program on ubuntu and it worked. I guess this is related to OS.